# Loop not giving me desired matrix output

Tags: java, loops, matrix

I am trying to display an array of numbers in a square matrix that increases by 1 in a snake pattern. Cant get right output. User inputs row/columns and matrix is displayed. Look at photo below. I have also attempted if statements for even/odd rows with modulo but still getting same output. (Bear with me, I am new to this, sorry about format or if I'm missing information)

https://i.stack.imgur.com/wgVJH.jpg

```
import java.util.Scanner;



public class A3_Q2 {

public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("[-------------------------]");
    System.out.println("[      Array Pattern      ]");
    System.out.println("[-------------------------]");

    System.out.println("How many rows/columns do you want your array to have? (Mist be at least 3):");


    int arraySize = keyboard.nextInt();

    while(arraySize < 3) 
    {
        System.out.println("Lets try this again ....");
        System.out.println("How many rows/columns do you want your array to have? (Mist be at least 3):");
        arraySize = keyboard.nextInt(); 
    }


    int [][] pattern = new int[arraySize][arraySize];

    int i = 0;
    int number = 1;

    while (i < arraySize) 
    {   
        for (int j = 0; j < arraySize; ++j)
        {
            pattern[i][j] = number;
            System.out.printf("%3d", pattern[i][j]);
            number++;   
        }   

        System.out.println("");
        ++i;
        for (int j = arraySize-1; j >= 0; --j)

        {
        pattern[i][j] = number;
        System.out.printf("%3d", pattern[i][j]);
        number++;   
        }

        System.out.println("");
        ++i;    
    }   
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've changed your code so that it works. As you already mentioned, you can use the modulo operator here.

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{

    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("[-------------------------]");
    System.out.println("[      Array Pattern      ]");
    System.out.println("[-------------------------]");

    System.out.println("How many rows/columns do you want your array to have? (Mist be at least 3):");


    int arraySize = keyboard.nextInt();

    while(arraySize < 3)
    {
        System.out.println("Lets try this again ....");
        System.out.println("How many rows/columns do you want your array to have? (Mist be at least 3):");
        arraySize = keyboard.nextInt();
    }


    int [][] pattern = new int[arraySize][arraySize];

    int number = 1;

    for(int i=0;i<arraySize;i++){
        if(i%2==0){
          for(int j=0;j<arraySize;j++){
               pattern[i][j]=number;
                number++;
             }
        }
        else{
            for(int j=arraySize-1;j>=0;j--){
                pattern[i][j]=number;
                number++;
            }
        }
        for(int j=0;j<arraySize;j++){
            System.out.printf("%3d", pattern[i][j]);
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

Comment: Ah ok i see where my mistake was when I used if/else. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: Tested this in IDE to make sure it works.

You first need to have have an initial value for pattern[i][j].

```
for (int i = 0; i < arraySize; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < arraySize; j++) {
        pattern[i][j] = arraySize*i + j + 1;
    }
}
```

You need to then have a condition that will print out the numbers in ascending order when i is even, and descending when i is odd.

```
for (int i = 0; i < arraySize; i++) {
    if (i % 2 == 0) {
       for (int j = 0; j < arraySize; j++) {
           System.out.printf("%3d", pattern[i][j]);
       }
    } else {
       for (int j = arraySize - 1; j >= 0; j--) {
           System.out.printf("%3d", pattern[i][j]);
       }
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```